# OneToOne Spring Hibernate Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to add 2 values ​​"name" and "city" to my 2 tables using @OneToOne. I think I write incomplete code at @Controller and wrong at Thymeleaf code. Help me . Thanks very much

Student.java

```
package com.example.demo.models;

 import javax.persistence.Column;
  import javax.persistence.Entity;
 import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
 import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
public class Student {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "student_id")
private long studentId;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "home_address_id")
private Address address;

public long getStudentId() {
    return studentId;
}

public void setStudentId(long studentId) {
    this.studentId = studentId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Address getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
}
```

Address.java

```
package com.example.demo.models;

 import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
  import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
     import javax.persistence.Id;
  import javax.persistence.Table;

   @Entity
 @Table(name = "address")
 public class Address {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "address_id")
private long addressId;

@Column(name = "city")
private String city;

public long getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}

public void setAddressId(long addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

}
```

StudentRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.example.demo.models.Student;

public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {
Student findByName (String name);

}
```

StudentService.java

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.models.Student;
import com.example.demo.repository.StudentRepository;

@Service
public class StudentService {
@Autowired
private StudentRepository studentRepository;

public List<Student> findAll (){
    return studentRepository.findAll();
}

public Student findByName (String name) {
    return studentRepository.findByName(name);
    
}

public Student save (Student student) {
    return studentRepository.save(student);
}

}
```

StudentController.Java

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
   import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
  import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

 import com.example.demo.models.Student;
 import com.example.demo.service.StudentService;

  @Controller
 public class StudentController {
@Autowired
private StudentService studentService;

@GetMapping("/all")
public ModelAndView getAll (ModelAndView modelAndView, Student student) {
    modelAndView.addObject("student", studentService.findAll());
    modelAndView.setViewName("all");
    return modelAndView;
    
}
@GetMapping("/add")
public ModelAndView add (ModelAndView modelAndView, Student student) {
    modelAndView.addObject("add", student);
    modelAndView.setViewName("add");
    return modelAndView;
}

@PostMapping("/add")
public ModelAndView postAdd (ModelAndView modelAndView, Student student) {
    Student existStudent= studentService.findByName(student.getName());
    if (existStudent!=null) {
        modelAndView.setViewName("add");
    }
    else {
        studentService.save(student);
        modelAndView.setViewName("success");
    }
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

add.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"> 
<head>  
    <title>Add</title>  
</head>  
<body>
    <center>
        <form action="#" th:action="@{/add}" th:object="${add}" method="post">  
            <table>  
                <tr>  
                    <td><label for="name">Name</label></td>  
                    <td><input th:field="*{name}" type="text" name="name"></input></td>  
                </tr>  
                <tr>  
                    <td><label for="city">City</label></td>  
                    <td><input th:field="*{address.city}" type="text" name="address.city"></input> 
           </td>  
                </tr>  
                
                <tr>  
                    <td><input type="submit" value="Submit"></input></td>  
                </tr>  
            </table>  
        </form>  
        </center>
       </body>  
       </html>
```

student.sql

```
create table student (
  student_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  home_address_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id),
  CONSTRAINT student_address FOREIGN KEY (home_address_id) REFERENCES ADDRESS ( address_id)
   );
```

Address.sql

```
 create table ADDRESS (
  address_id BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  city  VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (address_id)
  );
```

I think I am wrong and may write incomplete. If possible, rewrite code snippets I need to fix or add. Thanks very much

Comment: When I run it in the browser, it still shows me two input forms. When I enter 2 information such as name: John, City: Washington and then click send, the browser reports an error. Checks data in the database that no values ​​have been added

Comment: please help meeee